# VSCode karate robotframework cannot instantiate robot

Tags: visual-studio-code, robotframework, karate

I have try to run in VSCode the demo **calc.feauture** and and get the following error message:

ERROR com.intuit.karate - cannot instantiate robot, is 'karate-robot' included as a maven / gradle dependency ? com.intuit.karate.robot.RobotFactory

ERROR com.intuit.karate - src/demo/robot/calc.feature:7
*robot { window: 'Calculator', fork: 'calc', highlight: true, highlightDuration: 500 }
cannot instantiate robot, is 'karate-robot' included as a maven / gradle dependency ? com.intuit.karate.robot.RobotFactory
src/demo/robot/calc.feature:7

I am asking you for help, what else should be installed.

Comment: please read the instructions here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Karate-Robot-Windows-Install-Guide